# BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer'

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have spring boot application and i am trying to load application context from an another jar. This jar has some common methods, so every module import this jar to those common methods. I am using to @ImportResource to load context xml file of jar.

```
@ImportResource({"classpath:META-INF/spring/serviceApplicationContext.xml"})
```

**serviceApplicationContext.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"  
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

     <!-- The @AspectJ support is enabled by including the below tag -->     
     <aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>  

     <!-- Aspect -->  
     <bean id="loggingAspect" class="com.mellon.hris.hsa.aspect.LoggingAspect" />  

    <!--
        The variable testDatasourceContextXmlSuffix is set in pom.xml as a
        configuration of maven-surefire-plugin. So this variable will be set
        when unit tests are run. ie
        serviceApplicationContext_dataSources_test.xml will be loaded when
        running maven test otherwise serviceApplicationContext_dataSources.xml
        will be loaded.
    -->


    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties" />

    <!-- <import    resource="serviceApplicationContext_dataSources${testDatasourceContextXmlSuffix:}.xml" /> -->
    <import resource="classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext-common.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext-SoapWebservice.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath*:META-INF/spring/serviceApplicationContext-SoapWebservice.xml" />

    <bean id="applicationProperties" class="com.mellon.hris.hsa.util.PropertiesUtil">
         <property name="locations">
          <list>
             <!--  <value>classpath:#{systemProperties['config.env'].toLowerCase()}/Location.properties</value>
              <value>classpath:#{systemProperties['config.env'].toLowerCase()}/#{systemProperties['client.HPPCode']}Location.properties</value> -->

               <value>classpath:test/Location.properties</value>
          </list>
      </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="oracleDatasource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>java:comp/env/jdbc/hsawebsite</value>
        </property>
        <property name="resourceRef">
            <value>false</value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="db2Datasource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>java:comp/env/jdbc/MFDB2</value>
        </property>
        <property name="resourceRef">
            <value>false</value>
        </property>
    </bean>





    <bean id="dsMETASCANDatasource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName">
            <value>java:comp/env/jdbc/dsMETASCAN1</value>
        </property>
        <property name="resourceRef">
            <value>false</value>
        </property>
    </bean>


    <!--
        Turn on AspectJ @Configurable support. As a result, any time you
        instantiate an object, Spring will attempt to perform dependency
        injection on that object. 
    -->
    <context:spring-configured />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.mellon.hris.hsa">
        <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation" />
    </context:component-scan>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="oraTransactionManager" proxy-target-class="false"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="db2TransactionManager" proxy-target-class="false"/>
    <!-- 1065-Employer Profile - Address update -Start -->
<!--    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="oraEmsTransactionManager" proxy-target-class="false"/> -->
    <!-- 1065-Employer Profile - Address update -End -->

    <bean id="oraTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="oracleDatasource"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="db2TransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="db2Datasource"/>
    </bean>
    <!-- 1065-Employer Profile - Address update -Start -->
<!--    <bean id="oraEmsTransactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager"> -->
<!--        <property name="dataSource" ref="oracleEMSDatasource"/> -->
<!--    </bean> -->
    <!-- 1065-Employer Profile - Address update -End -->
    <bean id="oracleLobHandler" class="org.springframework.jdbc.support.lob.OracleLobHandler"/>


    <bean id="oraSqlMapClient"
          class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:META-INF/ibatis/oraSqlMapConfig.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="oracleDatasource" />
        <property name="lobHandler" ref="oracleLobHandler"></property>
    </bean>    

    <bean id="db2SqlMapClient"
          class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation">
         <!--    <value>classpath:META-INF/ibatis/db2SqlMapConfig.xml</value> -->
            <value>classpath:META-INF/ibatis/#{systemProperties['client.HPPCode']}db2SqlMapConfig.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="db2Datasource" />

    </bean>
    <!-- 1065-Employer Profile - Address update -Start -->
   <!--  <bean id="emsOraSqlMapClient"
          class="org.springframework.orm.ibatis.SqlMapClientFactoryBean">
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:META-INF/ibatis/emsOraSqlMapConfig.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="dataSource" ref="oracleEMSDatasource" />
        <property name="lobHandler" ref="oracleLobHandler"></property>

    </bean>  -->
    <!-- 1065-Employer Profile - Address update -End -->

    <bean class="com.mellon.hris.hsa.util.FlexPropertyConfigManager" factory-method="setStaticProperties" autowire="byName" scope="singleton">
            <constructor-arg ref="commonService" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl"
        id="mailSender">
        <property name="javaMailProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.host">${email.host}</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.port">${email.port}</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.username">${email.username}</prop>
                <prop key="mail.smtp.password">${email.password}</prop>
                <!-- Added timeout for SMTP servers as part of HSA_1392 -->
                <prop key="mail.smtp.timeout">${email.timeout}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="emailProperties"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
        <property name="location"
            value="classpath:META-INF/spring/email.properties" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="com.mellon.hris.hsa.util.EmailUtility" factory-method="setStaticProperties" autowire="byName" scope="singleton">
        <constructor-arg ref="emailProperties" />
        <constructor-arg ref="mailSender" />
        <constructor-arg ref="commonService" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="com.mellon.hris.hsa.util.CacheRefreshHandler" factory-method="setStaticProperties" autowire="byName" scope="singleton">
        <constructor-arg ref="accountService" />
    </bean>

    <bean class="com.mellon.hris.hsa.util.AuditHelper" factory-method="setStaticProperties" autowire="byName" scope="singleton">
        <constructor-arg ref="commonService" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="log4jInitialization"
     class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
       <property name="targetClass"
          value="org.springframework.util.Log4jConfigurer" />
       <property name="targetMethod" value="initLogging" />
       <property name="arguments">
          <list>
             <!-- <value>classpath:#{systemProperties['config.env'].toLowerCase()}/log4j.properties</value> -->
             <value>classpath:test/log4j.properties</value>
          </list>
       </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

When i trying to run my spring boot application  i am getting the below exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private com.ibatis.sqlmap.client.SqlMapClient com.mellon.hris.hsa.dao.impl.AccountDAOImpl.oraSqlMapClient; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oraSqlMapClient' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/serviceApplicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'oracleDatasource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oracleDatasource': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:331) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
        ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oraSqlMapClient' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/serviceApplicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'oracleDatasource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'oracleDatasource': Post-processing of FactoryBean's singleton object failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceAutoConfiguration$NonEmbeddedConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Cannot determine embedded database driver class for database type NONE. If you want an embedded database please put a supported one on the classpath. If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to active it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Please help me, i am stuck on this issue.

Comment: You need to connect Spring Boot with some database.

Comment: I don't understand, how this is related to that ?

Comment: do you have any profile specific database connections ? it seems no profile is provided and spring can not determine database driver class. I see from config you have Oracle and DB2 connections.